# kotilin: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I want to reveive value that i passed throught Intent from activity to another and access it, but it's showing:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

So here what i did... in the **Login Activity** I passed **username** thourgh Intent:

```
val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("username", "johnDoe")
startActivity(intent)
```

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val username = intent.getStringExtra("username")

    private val firebaseHelper = FirebaseHelper(username)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, username.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        firebaseHelper.deleteDriver()
    }
}
```

**Fore example**: if i use `val username = intent.getStringExtra("username")` it will work, but then i will get problem with `firebaseHelper.deleteDriver()`.

i don't know where i missed it, but hope there's solution you can make guys

Comment: and how is that suppose to help, that nothing to do with my question @Hypino

Comment: I dont know Kotlin. However  in MainActivity where was intent declared? As for your question, you are probably using an intent you haven´t recieved yet. I think Android sends it onNewIntent(); I dont think you can set Activity based variables in the get go. For example, I did... java.io.File appDir = Activity.this.getFilesDir(); My app kept crashing! What I had to do was initialize this variable in onCreate();

Answer (score 0):

You should call this code `val username = intent.getStringExtra("username")` in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: but i want to use `username` in `onStop` too

Comment: declare them globally in your ```MainActivity``` class ->  
```lateinit var firebaseHelper = FirebaseHelper``` and ```lateinit var username: String```. Then you can create your ```FirebaseHelper``` instance in ```onCreate``` method

Answer (score 0):

initailize

```
val username = intent.getStringExtra("username")
```

inside **oncreate**()

In **onstop** when firebaseHelper.deleteDriver() executes,
it get username as null. So it is throwing NPE

Comment: what about if i have other funtions accessing `username` what should i do, since it only works at `onCreate`